# C# UnitTest System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to test IpHostEntry knowledge with Mock in C# but and I get the error I wrote in the header. How can I fix this. The codes I wrote are as follows:

```
 Mock<ILogin> dnsMock = new Mock<ILogin>();
 dnsMock.Setup(d => d.mySelfIp(It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new SocketException());

 this.mock2 = dnsMock.Object;
 

 [TestMethod]
 public void are_ip_addresses_correct()
 {
      string hostName = "BERKAYKUCUK";
      var actualLogin = new Login();
      var actual = actualLogin.mySelfIp(hostName);

      var expected = this.mock2.mySelfIp(hostName);

      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // test correct object found
 }
```

Comment: You are throwing it? `dnsMock.Setup(d => d.mySelfIp(It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new SocketException());`

Comment: Yes ,I get this error for this line. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to reference a nonexistent socket. Expected object Null returns the actual true.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear. What do you want to test? Should `actualLogin.mySelfIp(hostName)` throw an exception? If so, Assert.AreEqual is not the right method to test it.

Comment: This is the function I want to test. Do I get the correct information? I want to know this and I wrote the test as above but I got socketexception.

Comment: public IPHostEntry mySelfIp(string  hostName)
{                 
       IPHostEntry mySelf = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName);
         return mySelf;
}